# Windows Client vs Web Client

Tags: java, asp.net, sql-server, webclient

I have a discussion going on in the organisation where I am employed as a consultant.
The discussion revolves around the replacement of an application built using VB6(MDI) thick client.

This application has around 100 screen + 40 reports. Used by approx 400 users the reports and the data are pulled using inline queries while the db structure is pretty normalized. the rest of the code is pretty bad.

While discussing replenishment strategies we are throwing around a few ideas.

1. J2EE Web application running on Web sphere using Crystal reports for Reports.
2. ASP.NET web forms web application using crystal reports for reports.
3. Windows Client application (WPF/Win-forms) with reporting services for  the reports.

While I don't want to start a flame war (Dot net vs. Java or WEb vs. Desktop) it would be nice to know the community thoughts on the matter. 
Just to be upfront I feel that option 3 maybe the best version, but I would like to know the opinions of others.

Comment: what technologies is the development team familiar with?

Comment: Added sql-server tag because you mentioned reporting services, correct?

Comment: I think you ask this question better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about

Answer (score 1):

A key question you have to ask/discover is whether or not you really need to replicate the existing functionality.  You'll probably find that with changes in the business workflow and improvements in technology that you don't need to build a hundreds of pages and 40 reports solution.

If you do more or less have to replace it then any of the 3 technologies can do the trick.  They key is to *prototype*.  Try each of them out before you settle on one.

Answer (score 1):

To add to karianna's response ... Be Careful. You will more than likely fall into the [Second System Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-system_effect). A better approach would be to leave the existing system in place, and just make new features with one of the new technologies and slowly start migrating. Don't plan on doing a pick up and drop migration to "the new version"

Answer (score 1):

How heavy is the VB6 app with third-party controls and the like? Could you replicate those in a browser-based UI ?

Comment: Just a single third party control vsflexgrid but lottsa customer built user controls.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add to the excellent remarks here, that part of your considerations might involve the system "statbility". If your app is going to require a frequent updates, then a web approach might be better. If the app is going to be stable, a desktop client is probably going to be much cheaper to build.

Comment: Updates aregoing to be maybe once a month .I agree that a winclient will be cheaper  but what are the other factors that are a advantage

Answer (score 1):

It's never easy to convert an "old" applications to a different platform.
It takes time to learn new technologies and implement it in the best way.

Since you're familiar with VB6 I would suggest you to consider ASP.NET MVC using VB.NET as a programming language.

I've developed a few WebForm web apps in the past but I've never felt really comfortable with it: 
- too many events to manage
- hassles with postbacks and viewstates

ASP.NET MVC is, let's say, more intuitive. I love it.
You can add jQuery (or another javascript framework) to obtain a more fluid interface.
As a reporting tool I've used and hated Crystal Reports.
I much prefer the RDL/RDLC format (reporting services). You have a designer integrated in Visual Studio and can even build the XML from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

From a deployment and support perspective, 1 or 2: no client install needed.

I'd suggest Winforms *only* if you need complex presentation or flow that would be hard to capture in a web page. That said, there is Flash and Silverlight etc for that...